# Convert dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm am/pm to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I want to convert  a string : `24/11/2016 04:30 pm` to datetime value : `11/24/2016 04:30 pm`.

My code as :

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("24/11/2016 04:30 pm", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get a error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What can I do ?

Comment: `DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("24/11/2016 04:30 pm", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Tks @Pikoh . I got it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the AM/PM designator you have to use `tt` not `aa`. [Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#tSpecifier):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("24/11/2016 04:30 pm", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `ParseExact` as always saves the world :)

Comment: OMG . It's easy . Thank you .